# Validate inputs in table rows sequentially

Tags: jquery

i have a table with repeating rows, each having some inputs and dropdowns with same class. when i click the submit button, i want validation to happen once for each row, and dont want to validate for same input of each row. for ex

i have this html:

```
<form method="post">
    <table width="100%" class="tableclass">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="abc" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="def" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="ghi" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="abc" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="def" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="ghi" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="abc" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="def" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="ghi" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="sbmt" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Here if i click submit button, and user has not entered first input of the first row, and has entered first input of second row, then validation should move to next input of the same row, not checking if fitst input of second row is empty or not.
in other words, validation should check for a row at a time fully, then move to next row, but with my below code, validation is checking for each .abc input of each row, then checking for .def input and so on, which i dont want.

```
$(function () {
    $(".sbmt").click(function () {
        $(".tableclass tr").each(function () {
            if ($(this).find(".abc").val() == '') {
                $("#err").html("abc empty")
                return false
            } else if ($(this).find(".def").val() == '') {
                $("#err").html("def empty")
                return false
            } else if ($(this).find(".ghi").val() == '') {
                $("#err").html("ghi empty")
                return false
            } else {
                $(".sbmt").submit();
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code. Fix them and try.

Comment: can you site me some errors?

Comment: missing `else if` at line 13

Comment: I did the change, but i write this code in running fashion while posting this question, as my actual code is not available right now, just to give you idea of what i was doing.

Comment: change your input type from `submit` to `button`